# How to smooth loading photos and keep the quality by using Photos framework?

Tags: ios, photos, phasset, photosframework

I'm trying to get photos from library and show it in a `collectionView`. My `collectionView` is enable paging. There is my code and it works:

```
- (void)fetchImage:(PHAsset *)asset completion:(void(^)(UIImage *image))completion {
    //Fetch image from asset
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    CGFloat scaleWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * scale;
    CGFloat scaleHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * scale;
    CGSize retinaSquare = CGSizeMake(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    
    representedAssetIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", asset.localIdentifier];
    
    PHImageRequestOptions *option = [PHImageRequestOptions new];
    option.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeFast;
    option.synchronous = YES;
    
    [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:asset
                                               targetSize:retinaSquare
                                              contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                                  options:option
                                            resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                                                // Set the cell's thumbnail image if it's still showing the same asset.
                                                if ([representedAssetIdentifier isEqualToString:asset.localIdentifier]) {
                                                    completion(result);
                                                }
                                            }];
}
```

And in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PhotosCell *cell = (PhotosCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:[self cellIdentifier] forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    PhotoItemModel *item = _controller.assetModels[indexPath.row];
    
    [_controller fetchImage:item.asset completion:^(UIImage *image) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.imageItem.image = image;
            cell.imageItem.clipsToBounds = YES;
            cell.imageItem.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        });
    }];
    
    return cell;
}
```

But I have a issue: when I trying to scroll to next photo, the `collectionView` is not coarse. It is delayed in a while.
I know the issue come from the code `option.synchronous = YES;`. When I remove this code, the `collectionView` is smooth. But I get the other issue: Sometimes, the quality of photo is not good. Like that:
True image:

[image]

"Sometimes":

[image]

My question is: how to smooth loading photos and keep the quality of photos?

Comment: You can dispatch your `- (void)fetchImage: completion:` method calling in a background thread.

Comment: @nayem: Thanks for your comment. I tried to put it in in background. But I get crash when I add this code: `dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        //fetch image in background
    });`

Comment: What's the crash log?